# Less Data is getting inserted database after running Jmeter script

Tags: jmeter

I recorded .jmx script by recording Blazemeter tool.

I followed below steps:

1. Login into application.

   [image]
2. By default user landed on page which is Search Page where Patient list is displayed.

   [image]
3. Now I select Patient and Navigate to Flowsheet page by clicking on HD Flowsheet menu button. Patient selection is mandatory.

   [image]
4. Saved Flowsheet.

   [image]
5. Logged Out.

Thread Group Detail:

Action to be taken after a Sample error: Continue

```
Number of Threads(users): 10
Ramp-up period (seconds): 100 
Loop Count: 1

Same User on each Iteration : Yes
```

After executing script with above Thread group, In database only 6 Flowsheet is getting inserted instead of 10 flowsheet.

I checked View Result Tree, It is showing no error and also in Summary report it is showing 0% error.

What can be root cause? What strategy I should follow in such cases to debug script?

Comment: Do you have indication if Saved Flowsheet was successful?

Comment: I used to check database to verify that flowsheet is saved or not.

Comment: Check Saved Flowsheet response if success

Comment: In View result tree it shows Success, But In actual, No Data is not inserted in DB and neither showing on screen.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter automatically treats [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful, it won't do any extra checks for the "flowshit" creation or insertion simply because it doesn't know anything about it.

My expectation is that your test silently fails somewhere, add [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and inspect response details for each step, most probably you will see that either you're submitting the same flowsheet over and over again or your script got stuck somewhere.

If you want to add an extra layer of verification, i.e. ensure that response contains specific value, you can add a [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to each request and specify pass/fail criteria there

In general when it comes to modern web applications the chance you will be able to successfully replay recorded script is close to zero because there are multiple dynamic parameters involved like ID of the patient or flowsheet, cookies, tokens, etc. and these dynamic values need to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/)